# CoffeeScript: making a callback more generic

Tags: jquery, callback, coffeescript

I have some pretty simple code. Unfortunately, at the bottom of that code is a callback with some hard-coded jQuery selectors, and I'd like to find a way to bring them out.

For the purpose of this exercise, let us assume that:

- .text-shows-up-here is where the text shows up
- .user-types-here is where the user actually enters the text

It's simple: user types somewhere, text is replicated somewhere else. Here is the code.

```
class TextChanger
  constructor: (@selector) ->
    events = ['change', 'keydown', 'keyup', 'keypress']
    @bind(event) for event in events

  update_text: ->
    $('.text-shows-up-here').text $('.user-types-here').val()

  bind: (event) ->
    @selector.on(event, @update_text)

window.Try ?= {}
window.Try.textChanger ?= TextChanger
```

And on the other side, in Javascript land...

```
    var textChanger = new Try.textChanger($('.user-types-here'));
```

I'd like to know if/how I can bring those two hard-coded selectors out of this callback in the 'bind' function:

```
  bind: (event) ->
    @selector.on(event, @update_text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class TextChanger
  constructor: (options) ->
    @source = options.source
    @target = options.target
    events = ['change', 'keydown', 'keyup', 'keypress']
    @bind(event) for event in events

  update_text: =>
    @target.text @source.val()

  bind: (event) ->
    @selector.on(event, @update_text)

window.Try ?= {}
window.Try.textChanger ?= TextChanger
```

And on the JS side...

```
var textChanger = new Try.textChanger({ 
                                        source: $('.user-types-here'), 
                                        destination: $('.text-shows-up-here')
                                     });
```

The key was to create update_text with '=>'. The [Coffeescript docs](http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow) are clear:

> In JavaScript, the 'this' keyword is dynamically scoped to mean the
>   object that the current function is attached to. If you pass a
>   function as a callback or attach it to a different object, the
>   original value of 'this' will be lost. If you're not familiar with this
>   behavior, this Digital Web article gives a good overview of the
>   quirks.
>
> The fat arrow => can be used to both define a function, and to bind it
>   to the current value of 'this', right on the spot. This is helpful when
>   using callback-based libraries like Prototype or jQuery, for creating
>   iterator functions to pass to each, or event-handler functions to use
>   with bind. **Functions created with the fat arrow are able to access
>   properties of the 'this' where they're defined.**

Answer (score 1):

You're already injecting the `.user-types-here`; inject the other one as well, and just use those objects in place of the jQuery selectors.

```
constructor: (options) ->
  @source = options.source
  @target = options.target
  ...

update_text: ->
  @target.text @source.val()
```

On your pure javascript side, just send them in:

```
var textChanger = new Try.textChanger({ 
                                        source: $('.user-types-here'), 
                                        destination: $('.text-shows-up-here')
                                     });
```

Comment: I tried something like that. It works fine if I call it manually "new Try.textChanger({s: x, t: y}).update_text()   -- but it's not nearly as awesome as far as working as a bound event.

Comment: What do you mean? What happens?

Comment: @Trevoke: What exactly did you try? Did you account for `@`'s value in a jQuery callback?

Comment: @muistooshort your question is precisely my problem.

Comment: @muistooshort here's the code, based on PaulPhillips' answer: https://gist.github.com/Trevoke/103ac73a4cd8951e098d

Comment: @Trevoke: Have you tried any of the usual solutions such as `_this = @` or `=>`?

Comment: @muistooshort Not sure how to do this, since it's a callback.